# UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource custom subclass initialization

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, init, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

So I am making a custom subclass of UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.

My code looks like this :

```
class MyDiffableDataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String> {
    
    convenience required init(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        self.init(collectionView: collectionView) { (collection, index, item) in
            if index.item % 2 == 0 {
                return self.firstCell(collection, item, index)
            } else {
                return self.secondCell(collection, item, index)
            }
        }
        self.supplementaryViewProvider = { (_, _, index) in
            return self.header(collectionView, index)
        }
    }
    
    func firstCell(_ collection: UICollectionView, _ item: String, _ index: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewListCell {
        let cellReg = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { (cell, _, item) in
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = item
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            cell.accessories = [.disclosureIndicator()]
        }
        return collection.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellReg, for: index, item: item)
    }
    
    func secondCell(_ collection: UICollectionView, _ item: String, _ index: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewListCell {
        let cellReg = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { (cell, _, item) in
            var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            content.text = item
            cell.contentConfiguration = content
            cell.accessories = [.checkmark()]
        }
        return collection.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellReg, for: index, item: item)
    }
    
    func header(_ collection: UICollectionView, _ index: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerReg = UICollectionView.SupplementaryRegistration
        <UICollectionReusableView>(elementKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader) { (_, _, _) in }
        return collection.dequeueConfiguredReusableSupplementary(using: headerReg, for: index)
    }
}
```

But of course I get the **'self' used before 'self.init' call or assignment to 'self'** error from Xcode.

How can I initialize MyDiffableDataSource only with a UICollectionView parameter without getting this error?

I know i can make the functions `firstCell()` and `secondCell()` static, or that i can put all the content of the two functions directly in the init. But that would not be great if i add more later and static would prevent me from accessing other non static properties.

Is there any other solutions that I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever solved this one? I cannot comprehend how stupid this initialiser is and I already wasted too many hours trying to overcome this error.

Comment: Hi @Adam, unfortunately i couldn't find a solution to this problem yet..!